# Create Instance with HTTP enable from Java Google Cloud

Tags: java, http, google-cloud-platform

Im using the following code to create an instance from Java using Google Cloud java(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java)

```
public class CreateInstance {

  public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
    Compute compute = ComputeOptions.defaultInstance().service();
    ImageId imageId = ImageId.of("debian-cloud", "debian-8-jessie-v20160329");
    NetworkId networkId = NetworkId.of("default");
    AttachedDisk attachedDisk = AttachedDisk.of(AttachedDisk.CreateDiskConfiguration.of(imageId));
    NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.of(networkId);
    InstanceId instanceId = InstanceId.of("us-central1-a", "instance-name");
    MachineTypeId machineTypeId = MachineTypeId.of("us-central1-a", "n1-standard-1");
    Operation operation =
        compute.create(InstanceInfo.of(instanceId, machineTypeId, attachedDisk, networkInterface));
    operation = operation.waitFor();
    if (operation.errors() == null) {
      // use instance
      Instance instance = compute.getInstance(instanceId);
    }
  }
}
```

Evrything works fine but all the created instances have HTTP and HTTPS diable by default, how can I create Instances with HTTP enable by Default.

I already have this approach:

```
Firewall firewall = new Firewall();
    firewall.setName(name);
    Firewall.Allowed allowedTCP8080 = new Firewall.Allowed();
    allowedTCP8080.setIPProtocol("tcp");
    List<String> ports = new ArrayList<>();
    ports.add("80");
    ports.add("8080");
    ports.add("8280");
    ports.add("8180");
    ports.add("9610");
    allowedTCP8080.setPorts(ports);
    List<Firewall.Allowed> allowedPorts = new ArrayList<>();
    allowedPorts.add(allowedTCP8080);
    firewall.setAllowed(allowedPorts);
    firewall.setDescription("httpports");
    firewall.setNetwork(googleCloudUtils.networkId.network());
```

But I do not know how to attach the firewall to the Network config and/or Instance.

Comment: What version of the API are you using? I don't see the Firewall class anywhere when I look at the source.

Comment: @WillHayworth      Version 0.3:
   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-compute</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
It is in this package package com.google.api.services.compute.model;

Answer (score 2):

I just figure out how to solve this.

1. set the instance tag to "http-server" while creating the instance
2. create a firewall rule named exactly "default-allow-http", I tried other names, but failed to apply to the instance.
3. set the targettage to "http-server".

remember you just need to set the firewall with the name once, otherwise you will get a "name exist error".

if you do not understand what's going on here, just type

```
gcloud compute --project "projectname" firewall-rules create "default-allow-http" --allow tcp:80 --network "default" --source-ranges "0.0.0.0/0" --target-tags "http-server"
```

in the terminal and then go to console to see what happened on the network-firewall page.